# Body of revoltion, volume element

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Assume we have a continuous function $y=f(x)>0$ and $x\in [a,b]$ which is revolved about the $x$-axis. Let $\theta$ be the angle of revolution (w.r.t $y$-axis) then why is the volume element given by
$$dV=yd\theta dy dx$$

Comment: (w.r.t. y-axis ) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is volume $dV$?

When our variables are $y$ and $\theta$ with a boundary, what volume do they cover?

$$dV=dx \times dy \times (yd\theta)$$

[image: d volume]

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If revolving is entirely w.r.t. x-axis, then

$$ dV = \pi y^2 dx $$

for a full revolution, and,

$$ dV =  (y^2/2) dx\, d\theta  $$

for a partial revolution.

$dy$  makes sense when you are referring to a hollow shell of revolution with two $y$ integration limits or constant radial thickness and so on ; when nothing is mentioned it will be assumed as a full solid. If an annular shell is considered, then

differential of

$$d (y^2) = 2 y dy $$

so that

$$ dV =  y dy \,dx \, d\theta  $$